# Voyager: "@php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1"

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

Been using tcg/voyager package in other projects and I had no problems with it until now.

Trying to install it in a new project would throw me this error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\DatabaseUserProvider::getModel()

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Veachy backs\Veachy (voyager admin)\vendor\tcg\voyager\src\VoyagerServiceProvider.php:101
     97|      */
     98|     public function boot(Router $router, Dispatcher $event)
     99|     {
    100|         if (config('voyager.user.add_default_role_on_register')) {
  > 101|             $model = Auth::guard(app('VoyagerGuard'))->getProvider()->getModel();
    102|             call_user_func($model.'::created', function ($user) use ($model) {
    103|                 if (is_null($user->role_id)) {
    104|                     call_user_func($model.'::findOrFail', $user->id)
    105|                         ->setRole(config('voyager.user.default_role'))

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Veachy backs\Veachy (voyager admin)\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:37
      TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::boot(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Router), Object(Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher))

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Veachy backs\Veachy (voyager admin)\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:37
      call_user_func_array()
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

This error will prevail in any next php artisan command, untill I remove the package.

Before this error I was required to update composer memory from 512M to 2G. Don't know if it related.

Already updated composer before installing package.

Version information
Laravel: v 7.22.4
PHP: 7.3.12

Thanks all,

Fernando

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because my project uses 'api' as default guard  instead of
'web' (config\auth.php):

```html
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
```

The workaround is to set 'VoyageGuard' in "app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php" to the guard(web) of your choice:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('VoyagerGuard', function () {
            return 'web';
        });
    }
```

Now Voyager will use web guard instead of api guard.

best regards